# How to set an button align-right with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap. The structure is a container within some context. At the bottom of the container, I put a button next to an description.

Now, I want to set the button align to the right without break the bootstrap structure.
What should I do? I had set the "float:right" to the button style, but it appeared bad.
The button is outside the "alert-info" background and not vertical align. Any better method?

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
<a href="#" class="alert-link">Summary:Its some description.......testtesttest</a>  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="float:right;">Large      button</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

### Bootstrap 5 implementation:

The class name is now **"float-end"** instead of *"pull-right"*

```
<div class="alert alert-info clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">
      Summary:Its some description.......testtesttest
    </a> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end">
      Large button
    </button>
</div>
```

---

### **Bootstrap 4 (and under) implementation:**

Just add a simple **pull-right** class to the button, and make sure the container div is clearfixed:

```
<div class="alert alert-info clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">
      Summary:Its some description.......testtesttest
    </a> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
      Large button
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: No idea why it worked, but I'm ok with it cuz it did what I wanted gloriously.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses `.float-right` as opposed to `.pull-right` in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Update: And Bootstrap 5 uses "float-end" and "float-start" to better support RTL languages..

Comment: As per @KolappanN - Bootstrap 4 uses `.float-right`. `.pull-right` does not work in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="text-right">
    <button type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `text-end` for Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 4):

**On bootstrap 4**, you can do this add `pull-right` to your classname:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-block pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Search</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apple</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sony</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="alert alert-info" style="min-height:100px;">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <a href="#" class="alert-link">Summary:Its some
           description.......testtesttest</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large      button</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Sx/1/

Comment: Smart! by grid system again.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This work for me in bootstrap 4:

```
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <a href="#" class="alert-link">Summary:Its some description.......testtesttest</a>  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right">Large button</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name `float-right`:

```
function Continue({show, onContinue}) {
  return(<div className="row continue">
  { show ? <div className="col-11">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" onClick= {onContinue}>Continue</button>
    </div>
    : null }
  </div>);
}
```