# Custom .CSS file/classes not importing to React Bootstrap app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

This is a continuation from [Trying to shift my React button based on numerical values (##px) doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660147/trying-to-shift-my-react-button-based-on-numerical-values-px-doesnt-work).

I'm trying to move a button my webpage based on whatever value I set right: ##px to, but no matter what value I try, the button doesn't move at all beyond a few set positions.

After doing some inspect element on the button, it turns out `btn-top-right` is nowhere in sight. Yet `btn`, `btn-primary`, and `float-end` show up on the button's styles/inspect element (whatever you'd like to call it).

Any thoughts?
Dash.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; // Import the Bootstrap CSS file
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import init from './Svg'
import axios from 'axios'

import classes from './Dash.module.css'
const Dash = (props) => {
...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-top-right float-end">CPU</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
...
}
```

and Dash.Module.css:

```
.btn-top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2000px;
    right: 50000px;
  }
```

[File/Directory Structure here (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89xMh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference given to Bootstrap.min.css is higher than your file. But you can overwrite it by using !important keyword

```
.btn-top-right {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 2000px !important;
    right: 50000px !important;
}
```

Comment: Giving that a try!

Comment: error fixed or not?

Comment: I ended up just using several `&emsp;` to space it out for now. So I'm not entirely sure if plugging in the !important keyword worked or not :(

Answer (score 1):

Since the class is absent I would suspect your code is being cached.

Try performing a hard reload `ctrl + shift + R` or launching your site in an incognito window.

Comment: Giving that a try!